# Is there a way to modify the CP home screen?

Tags: add-on, control-panel, extension

Are there any plugins available to update the layout / available list of actions on the home screen once a user is logged in?

Answer (score 6):

[dashEE](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/dashee) - is fully customizable ExpressionEngine control panel dashboard alternative.

> Module comes with 8 default widgets but you also have the ability to
>   develop your own tailored to your needs. In addition to developing
>   your own stand along widgets you can also incorporate dashEE widgets
>   into your existing custom EE modules instantly making your modules
>   more usable by introducing new functionality right on the EE CP
>   dashboard.

Comment: Thanks Max, it looks promising. The default list of widgets out of the box isn't the most exciting but I'll take a look at rolling my own.

Answer (score 1):

[Zoo Flexible Admin](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zoo-flexible-admin) is great for controlling and customizing what other member groups can see in admin control panel.

"Lets you fully customize the control panel menu per membergroup. Insert custom links, rename, re-order and remove menu items in order to create a more intuitive menu..."